# Bad Company 2 number besides the rank

Tags: battlefield-bad-company-2

Sometimes in the player listing I can see some players with a number inside a square, right beside their rank, which I'm not sure but I think is always 50.

What does that number inside the square represent?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you have it the other way around. The number that is typically in square is the Veteran Rank. Veteran rank is the number of previous Battlefield titles you have tied to your EA account. For example if you own bad company 2 and you also own battlefield 2 you would have a veteran rank of 1. You don't have to be rank 50 to have veteran rank either.

Hope that explains it.

Answer (score 3):

Another thing to add is that this veteran rank actually unlocks extra stuff in the game. In Bad Company 2 having a veteran rank of 1 or above will unlock the M1 Garand as a weapon. You can check these details and register old Battlefield games to your account at http://www.battlefieldbadcompany2.com/

Comment: Oh so that's how you get the M1 Garand. My Bad Company 2 came with a code for Battlefield 1943, does it count for the veteran rank?

Comment: @David Yes, it does. I'm not sure how much you have to play it for it to count, though.

Comment: Another easy way to get additional +1 to your veteran rank is play a few games of battlefield heroes (completely free game that runs out of a browser window) http://www.battlefieldheroes.com/en/frontpage/landingPage just make sure you sign up with the same email address, user account, etc